# SET LANGUAGE in SQL-Prozedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have tried to use "SET LANGUAGE Italian" in MSSQL Procedure in order to get the month name on Italian.
However stored procedure after executing does not return the query result. In case SET LANGUAGE is not used, the query result is displayed as usually.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE language
AS
BEGIN
SET LANGUAGE Italian;

...
SET query ='SELECT ....'
EXEC (query)

END
```

Comment: This is something your presentation layer should take care of. Let your DB return a typed date and do the formatting externally.

Comment: I found the other way - using FORMAT(@thedate, 'dddd', 'it-it') within SELECT statement you can get the day of the week on Italian.

Comment: Dana, I know this, but the approach is wrong... Just imagine, your project is really great and some day you are asked to use this in USA, Russia, Germany, China... What about the output? The Database should return typed data, while the presentation layer (a GUI, a report engine, whatever) should deal with formatting and localisation. Returning with `FORMAT()` will return a string (which looks like a date). Any further processing will have to be aware of italian to understand this.

Comment: Shnugo I get your point and I agree that the presentation layer should deal with formatting. But in this case the procedure is used only for research purposes in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because EXEC uses different context, just add set language inside : SET query = 'set language italian;SELECT ...'

you can also set the default language in the connexion user login properties